# open a directory with intellij without creating a project

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to be able to open a directory with intellij without creating a project.
how to do it? 
every time I open a folder, a project is automatically created with an .idea folder

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Intellij IDE to open a directory,

[image: use the Intellij IDE to open a directory]

It assumes that you are going to open a project (as it is the main reason to use IDEs). By default all of jetbrains's IDEs put the `project specific settings` for project in the `.idea` folder.

It is also **safe to delete** it if you are just opened a directory. There would be no problem in deleting this.

[image: Simply Delete .idea folder]

You can also use **Terminal tab** to change or open a directory (`Alt+F12`)
and use terminal commands to traverse between directories without creating any `.idea` folder.